# Mapping issue with Dapper: Stored procedure result not correctly mapped to class properties

Tags: database, stored-procedures, mapping, data-annotations, dapper

I am calling a stored procedure from my C# code and want to map the result to my custom class. However when calling the method the mapping is not happening correctly when using the column annotations. I don't want to rename my attributes to the column names.

I am new to Dapper and would appreciate some help.

Call to the stored procedure

```
 public async Task<HotelBedFactResponse> GetOneHotelBedFactAsync(int id)
    {
        using var connection = connectionFactory.Create();

        var parameters = new
        {
            Id = id
        };

        string query = "HotelBedFact_GetOne";

        var result = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<HotelBedFactResponse>(query, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        return result;
    }
```

The Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HotelBedFact_GetOne]
@Id int
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
    hbf.Id AS HotelBedFactId,
    f.Id AS FactId,
    hbf.Code AS HotelBedFactCode,
    hbf.GroupCode AS HotelBedFactGroupCode,
    f.Description AS HotelBedDescription
FROM HotelBedFact hbf
INNER JOIN Fact f ON f.Id = hbf.Fact_Id
WHERE hbf.Id = @Id;
END
```

The custom class

```
public class HotelBedFactResponse
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a Id for HotelBedFactResponse.
    [Column("HotelBedFactId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a FactId for HotelBedFactResponse.
    [Column("FactId")]
    public int FactId { get; set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a Code for HotelBedFactResponse.
    [Column("HotelBedFactCode")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a GroupCode for HotelBedFactResponse.
    [Column("HotelBedFactGroupCode")]
    public string GroupCode { get; set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a Description for HotelBedFactResponse.
    [Column("HotelBedDescription")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Dapper doesn't care about your annotations. You have to provide the mapping yourself. There is a nuget package Dapper.DataAnnotations, but I haven't used it, so I can't tell you how well it works.

Comment: Have you solved your problem already?